# Finding the curve of steepest ascent on an N-dimensional surface.

Tags: calculus

To find the 2D path of steepest ascent on a 3D surface $f$ we can use the slope of two gradient vector elements:

$$f(x,y) =  (50+(x/36)) \cdot (1 + (y/5000))$$
$$g = \nabla f = \{1/36 (1 + y/5000), (50 + x/36)/5000)\} $$

"For the curve $y(x)$ to be tangent to $∇f$, its slope must equal the rise-over-run of the 2d gradient vector."

Solving the differential system:
$$ y'(x) = (g_2 / g_1\text{ where: }y \rightarrow y(x)), \quad y(6600) = 3400 $$

Gives us the red line:
$$y(x) = -5000 + \sqrt{(1800 + x)^2}$$

[image: graph]

How can this be generalized to $N$-dimensional surfaces when it uses slope?

I tried this alternate method but the results don't make sense:

Solving the system:
$$x'(u) = g_1\text{ where: }y \rightarrow y(u),$$
$$y'(u) = g_2\text{ where: }x \rightarrow x(u),$$
$$x(10000) = 6600, y(10000) = 3400 $$

gives:

$$x(u) = -\frac{600 (3 E^{1/18} - 14 E^{u/180000})}{E^{1/18}}$$
$$y(u) = -\frac{200 (25 E^{1/18} - 42 E^{u/180000}}{E^{1/18}}$$

Which doesn't make any sense: since $x(0) = 6146.06, y(0) = 2946.06$ when $x(u) + y(u) = u$ should hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3D path on 4D surface:
$$f(x,y,z)=(50+(x/36))⋅(1+(y/5000))⋅(1+(z/3333))$$
$$g = ∇ f$$

Solve the differential system:
    $$ y'(x) = g_1/g_2 where: y → y(x), $$
    $$ z'(x) = g_1/g_3 where: \{y → y(x), z → z(x)\}, $$
    $$ y(4911) = 1711, z(4911) = 3378 $$

Gives:

$$y(x) = -3200 + x$$
$$z(x) = -1533 + x$$

[image]